# Active Admin does not save associated record into database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, activeadmin

I have created an Active Admin form to create a quiz with its own questions and answers.
The model association is fine.
I can save a Quiz with Questions and Answers from the console, but when I try to do the same with my form, just questions are stored in the database.
These are my ActiveAdmin controllers

```
ActiveAdmin.register Quiz do

  permit_params :title,
    questions_attributes: [:id, :title, :_destroy]

ActiveAdmin.register Question do

  permit_params :title,
    answers_attributes: [:id, :title, :_destroy]

ActiveAdmin.register Answer do

  permit_params :title
  belongs_to :question
```

What's wrong with them? Am I missing something?

**UPDATE**

```
## ActiveAdmin.register Quiz Form

  form do |f|
    f.inputs 'Name' do
      f.input :title
    end
    f.inputs do
      f.has_many :questions, allow_destroy: true, new_record: true do |q|
        q.input :title
        q.has_many :answers, allow_destroy: true, new_record: true do |a|
          a.input :title
        end
      end
    end
    f.actions
  end


## Question Model
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :quiz
    has_many :answers

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, allow_destroy: true

end
```

Comment: can you provide your Question Model in above

Comment: Can you post the code for the form? Are you using nested resources?